# Jax-ws : How to distinguish between not sent date field & incorrect date format?

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws

I'm creating a SOAP web service with Jax-ws.

I want to send a soap fault error when receiving a wrong date format from the request.

However, I'm always receiving a null value when the format is incorrect, and I have no way to distinguish between an incorrect date format & value not sent from the request ...

I tried to create a Date XmlAdapter and to throw the exception there,
but it seems that it is catched somewhere ...

I saw similar posts such as : [Jax ws- xs:date format validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397661/jax-ws-xsdate-format-validation)

but it is very dated (~ 4 years old) and not answered ...

Thanks for your help

EDIT:

***DateAdapter.java*** : The adapter class that throws the exception

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

    private final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) {
        synchronized (simpleDateFormat) {
            return simpleDateFormat.format(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws InvalidParameterFault {
        synchronized (simpleDateFormat) {
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = simpleDateFormat.parse(v);

                return date;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new InvalidParameterFault("Wrong date format");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***DocumentService.java***: The web service class

```
@MTOM
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.example.webservice", serviceName = "example-webservice")
@Slf4j
public class DocumentServerImpl implements DocumentServer {

    private CustomService customService;

    public DocumentServerImpl() {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
        customService = context.getBean(CustomService.class);
    }

    @Override
    public CustomDocument downloadDocument(String id) throws InvalidParameterFault {
        log.info("Download document with id <{}>", id);

        return customService.load(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String uploadDocument(CustomDocument document) throws InvalidParameterFault {
        log.info("Upload document");

        return customService.store(document);
    }

}
```

***CustomDocument.java*** : Schema class that contains the date to validate

```
@Setter
@XmlType(name = "CustomDocument")
public class CustomDocument {
    private DataHandler dataHandler;
    private Date customDate;

    public CustomDocument() {
    }

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
    public Date getCustomDate() {
        return this.customDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your Date XmlAdapter code

Comment: Here you are ! I'm very frustrated by Jax-ws since there is no documentation at all & easy way to validate input. Isn't it an obvious need while developing a web service ?

Comment: Can you post your annotated web service class (one using date is fine)?

Comment: Here you are, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Try my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@XmlRootElement
public class CustomDocument {
   private DataHandler dataHandler;
   private Date customDate;

     public CustomDocument() {
     }

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
    public Date getCustomDate() {
        return this.customDate;
    }
}
```

EDIT: responding to comments

From http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxb-and-package-level-xmladapters.html , at the package level, try

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=StringAdapter.class, type=String.class)
})
package xmladapter.bar;
```

You can also do this at type level.  See the url above.

Comment: When I add those new annotations `XmlRootElement` & `XmlAttribute`, the debugger doesn't go into DateAdapter methods ...

Comment: My bad, it's because it changed the XSD schema like this : <Document customDate="?">
            <dataHandler>cid:</dataHandler>
         </Document>

but I don't want it to be like that. I need the customDate to be at the same level as the dataHandler.